# What does "not relying on any parametric functional form to be postulated" mean?

Tags: nonparametric

I am reading the introduction section to a ml-book where I came across this sentence which I do not quite understand.

*The Gaussian process is a non-parametric and probabilistic model for nonlinear functions. Non-parametric means that it does not rely on any parametric functional form to be postulated.*

The second part I'd like a simpler explanation if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer to your question can be found online (*e.g.*, Wikipedia's article on nonparametric statistics - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics), I will go into some detail here.

Essentially. "nonparametric" means that no assumptions are made on the underlying data-generating process model. Here, a model consists of a number of parameters and variables combined together in some meaningful way. For instance, the Gaussian (normal) distribution

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$$

is one such parametric model having parameters $\mu$ (the population mean) and $\sigma^2$ (the population variance), and (random) variable $x$. Note some sources instead write the above expression in terms of the population standard deviation $\sigma$. in that case, the $\sigma^2$ under the square root is moved in front of it, becoming $\sigma$.

In most cases, population parameters are *unknown a priori* and therefore must be estimated (using a variety of techniques, such as the method of moments or maximum likelihood estimation).

I like to think of nonparametric as being equivalent to "data-driven", where we let the data do all of the talking. If you listen hard enough, your data will speak to you!